# Set up Sublime for Selenium Webdriver, Python, Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, sublimetext3, pytest

I am Selenium Webdriver Python developer, and I'm using PyCharm, but I would like to move on Sublime, is anyone can help with set up Sublime to run my tests with Pytest framework. When I try to run my test I'm getting in console output something like this `>>>` and this is it, it doesn't open browser and anything else.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PyTest ? You don't say how you are running your tests in Sublime. Presumably you want them to run on save or something?

Comment: @dpwrussell i installed that package pytest, what do you mean 'on save', running just Cmd + B. I'm sorry I'm new in Sublime. In Pycharm I'm just clicking Run test_sometest.py

Comment: By default it looks to be configured to run tests on save. You can set it to manual and assign a key to initiate the testing. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PyTest explains how. Let us know what you tried and what result you got.

Comment: @dpwrussell it worked somehow by itself, but still thanks for help

Comment: @dpwrussell and maybe you know, after test if it's failure red is message is shown like this https://packagecontrol.io/readmes/img/6cc259ed3d04df5d8f1c9a364f1564fa74983343.jpg , how can i close this message, ESC doesn't work

Comment: Fix the test/code that causes it! Otherwise, no idea. I'm pretty sure it's meant to be glaringly obvious when you have failures on purpose.